# How should session-wise contstant flags be refactored for a ZF2 site?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

I am working through the Zend Framework 2 tutorials in preparation to attempting to port a rather large existing application. I'm taking it piece by piece and just trying to get all the parts in their proper places inside the framework before buckling down to re-write all the code. A number of things are currently a mystery to me conceptually.

My existing application (circa 2006) used PHP constants to setup some basic mode/status flags that were persistent given the user's current session. The main config file did some tests to determine, for example, if the site was hosted on a production server or devel server, whether the site was in embedded mode, mobile browser mode, etc. The result of these tests was a number of boolean constants getting set.

```
// Decide if we are on a development server or not
// (enables debug features and experimental functionality)
define('DEVEL', !preg_match('!^(www.)?example.com$!', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']));

// Figure out what protocol to use when making CDN calls
define('PROTOCOL', ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80) ? 'http' : 'https');

// Mark which DB server to use
define('DB_SERVER', DEVEL ? 'localhost' : 'db.example.com');

// If we're running inside somebody else's frameset, various bits of the
// template get left out along the way (set with URL parameter)
define('EMBEDDED', check_if_embeded());

// Determine if the browser is a mobile device
define('MOBILE', mobile_device_detect());

// Check to see what features the user has (dis|en)abled
define('SOCIAL', get_user_pref('social'))
define('COMPACT_THEME', get_user_pref('compact_theme'));
```

These various factors are then taken into consideration as the template is built and in various parts of the app as they decide how much information should be spit out.

```
if (!MOBILE) {
    // Include code only runs on the full site
    if (SOCIAL) {
        // Include links social media tools
    }
}

if (COMPACT_THEME) {
    // Include extra style-sheet with smaller margins
}
```

Some of these have more logical places for them to be. For example the database server details go in the config for the module that will be making database calls. The embedded flag was, in this case, coming out of the URL, so I think that's going to get transfered into the router system somehow, and I'm thinking will be a different view altogether, although this seems like a good way to repeat code.

What isn't clear to me is what do do with the more generic state flags. A lot of these were used in the page layout templates. I could just hack some of them into the main application views and layout template, but that doesn't seem right.

At a conceptual level for a site attempting to follow an MVC pattern with ZF2, what would these flags be? Where would they be set and at what point in the pattern would they be checked?

Comment: Can you give a few more examples of the 'generic' flags and what they do?

Comment: @TimFountain Does that help at all? I've edited some more examples in of the sort of thing the template and output procedures are full of based on these flags.

Answer (score 2):

Those flags must be checked before dispatching the request.

The best place to check the flags will be the onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) method under your Module.php.

You can create an specific module for those flag checks. In this module you can configure your layout based on those flags.

That module can have only one file, the Module.php and all your code will be in the onBootstrap() method.

[EDIT]

To store those flag values you can either:

- Create layout variables
- Create a config value and store it in the service manager under any key

Comment: Thanks for this input, that actually helps a lot. Is there any chance you could [edit] this to be explicit about the best way to pass these type of flags around? Lets say I have a module that basically just sets these  run-time configuration flags in a bootstap method. How should the flags be accessed? Should I be setting something in the module variables or is setting constants a reasonable way to keep passing these around?

Comment: updated, now I cannot be more specific because of time. Later I will update with more details